# How to use AWS System Manger with Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-secrets-manager, aws-ssm

I have an AWS Amplify App and I am storing secrets in the AWS System Manager parameter store. According to the documentation, I followed this syntax `/amplify/{your_app_id}/{your_backend_environment_name}/{your_parameter_name}` and created this parameter `/amplify/abcdefgh1234/dev/MY_PARAM`. How do I use `MY_PARAM` in `amplify.yaml`? When I use `MY_PARAM` as stated below, I get empty values. I have added `/amplify/abcdefgh1234/dev/MY_PARAM` in `environment variables` section in amplify app setting.

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - echo ${secrets.MY_PARAM}
        - echo $secrets
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Role used in Amplify was missing permissions of SSM. I have added the below actions to the existing amplify role and it was able to fetch the parameters

```
 "ssm:PutParameter",
 "ssm:GetParametersByPath",
 "ssm:GetParameters",
 "ssm:GetParameter"
```

Comment: I am getting an error when trying to do this in order to declare a system manager variables in the yaml file

Answer (score 3):

yes granting SSM permission to AmplifySSRLoggingRole worked! Thanks!

Without SSM permission, error in clone repo stage:

```
2023-03-22T06:26:52.449Z [INFO]: SSM params {"Path":"/amplify/d2h3a4ocozujg5/prb/","WithDecryption":true}
2023-03-22T06:26:52.482Z [WARNING]: !Failed to set up process.env.secrets
```

After SSM permission, you can echo $secrets to test and write your secret to runtime .env if you like:

```
- yum install jq -y
- echo "KEY1=$(echo "$secrets" | jq -r '.KEY1')" > .env
- echo "KEY2=$(echo "$secrets" | jq -r '.KEY2')" >> .env
```

then in your code you can still use 'process.env.KEY1 or KEY2'